# Number of first element insertions to sort array in O(nlogn)?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

> If you am only allowed to move the first element of an array, how many insertions does it take to fully sort the array?
>
> In the output, give the number of insertions necessary as well as how many positions each element moves back.

For example:

Input:

```
6
1 4 2 5 3 6
```

Output:

```
4
3 4 2 4
```

Explanation:

This is the order of insertions:

```
4 2 5 1 3 6
2 5 1 3 4 6
5 1 2 3 4 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I can do this in O(n<sup>2</sup>) since the problem simplifies to finding the position where the first element lies in the increasing suffix of the array.
How can I solve this in O(nlogn)?

Comment: Hint: A binary search finds a position within a sorted array in O(log(size of sorted array)) operations.

Comment: I understand that using upperbound or lowerbound in c++ will be able to find the position in the suffix in log n time, but how do you know how many positions the first element moves back each time without simulating the process (since that would be too slow). Is there some clever way to keep track of the position of each element after an insertion?

Comment: @AndrewZhang: I think your question is that in your implementation, each iterative step takes O(log n) to determine where to place the next element, and O(n) to actually place it there. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Oh, I see. I think a red-black tree could track the number of descendants under each node without changing its operations' computational complexity? Not elegant, but if that's so, I think it works out.